# how to understand the conditional probability point of view of linear regression?

Tags: probability, linear-regression

in Andrew Ng's Machine learning course
 http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf

Page 12,it said: $x$ and $y$ has linear relationship
$$y(i) = \theta^Tx^{(i)}+\epsilon^{(i)}$$
where
$$ \epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$$ is assumed to be IID random Gaussian variable.Therefore 
$$ p(\epsilon^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}exp(-\frac{(\epsilon^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2})$$
and if we write
$$\epsilon^{(i)} = y(i) - \theta^Tx^{(i)}$$
we can obtain a **conditional probability**:
$$ p(y^{(i)} | x^{(i)};\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}exp(-\frac{(y(i) - \theta^Tx^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

My question is : why it's an **conditional probability?** rather than a 2**D-Joint probability**? That is, why can't I write it as this:
$$ p(y^{(i)} , x^{(i)};\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}exp(-\frac{(y(i) - \theta^Tx^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

one more question, in the notes, $y^{(i)}$ and $x^{(i)}$ are samples, not random variants, was it OK to write $ p(y^{(i)} | x^{(i)} )$ instead of $ p(Y | X)$

Thank you Brilliant guys!

Answer (score 1):

$p(\epsilon^{(i)})$ is the probability density function of the error term $\epsilon^{(i)}$.   It expresses how the unmoddled effects influence the value of $y^{(i)}$; that is the density function of the influence on $y^{(i)}$ that is *not* produced by random variable $x^{(i)}$ (or the parameter $\theta$).

In other words, for *a fixed value* of $x^{(i)}$,  then $p(\epsilon^{(i)})$ is the conditional density function of $y^{(i)}$ given that contraint.

$$p(y^{(i)}\mid x^{(i)};\theta)~=~p(\epsilon^{(i)})$$

---

> one more question, in the notes, $y^{(i)}$ and $x^{(i)}$ are samples, not random variants, was it OK to write $ p(y^{(i)} | x^{(i)} )$ instead of $ p(Y | X)$

Yes..ish.   It is actually shorthand for $p_{\lower{0.5ex}{X\mid Y}}(y^{(i)}\mid x^{(i)})$, just as the $p(\epsilon^{(i)})$ is actually $p_{\lower{0.5ex}\mathcal E}(\epsilon^{(i)})$ .   It is just that the subscripts are sometimes omitted when it is considered unambiguous as to what variable the value refers.

Comment: Thanks Graham! May I say it like this: "$\epsilon^{(i)}$ depends on only y, not x, therefore to describe the distribution of $\epsilon^{(i)}$, we can use the form of $p(Y|X)$ instead of $p(X,Y)$"?  Was it proper to say this?